# Ruby on Rails: How can I sign in with devise inside of my tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm having issues signing into Devise in my tests. I'm using the default testing suite in Rails.

In my test helper file, I've defined a log_in method like so:

```
  def log_in
    @user = User.create(id: 1)
    sign_in(:user, @user)
  end
```

I don't get any errors, the method just doesn't sign me in. I know this because I redirect the user when they are not signed in, and the result of one of my tests is:

```
ContentsControllerTest#test_should_show_content [E:/Uni/coursework/empire/test/controllers/contents_controller_test.rb:32]:
Expected response to be a <success>, but was <302>
```

sign_in is called in setup like so...

```
  setup do
    @content = contents(:one)
    log_in
  end
```

Any help on how I can sign in would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You also should

```
include Devise::TestHelpers
```

Here you have some code samples [Minitest+Devise](https://gist.github.com/jwo/7323240)

Comment: Yes I did, I can call the method but it just doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: The controller test? I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my issues by changing my log_in method to the following:

```
  def log_in
    sign_in(users(:one))
  end
```

The reason why I wasn't using a fixture in the first place was because I had an issue with the fixture which was causing some strange errors. Always check your fixtures.